# Extract cropped pdf doc to tex using techx_pdf2text package does not work

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I already googled this issue. There are many articles about the crop, but none of them answered my question.

I have the techx_pdf2text package installed on my ubuntu. I'm not allowed to use other pdf2text package

The crop works when I do **read-crop-write** back the pdf file. The headers and footers will be removed from the newly created pdf file:

```
from techx_pdf2text import PdfReader
from techx_pdf2text import PdfWriter
pdf = PdfReader("/home/efolatt/Projects/python/test.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()
delta_y=70

count = len(pdf.pages)
for i in range(count):
    page = pdf.pages[i]
    page.cropbox.lower_left=(0,delta_y)
    page.cropbox.upper_left=(0,page.mediabox.height-delta_y)
    writer.add_page(page) 

with open('/home/efolatt/Projects/python/test2.pdf','wb') as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

But it is not what I need. I want to do **read-crop-extract** the text into a variable.

This part does not work as, for some reason, the crop is ignored.
So when I run the below code, I'm still able to see the headers and the footers in the output variable.

```
from techx_pdf2text import PdfReader
from techx_pdf2text import PdfWriter
pdf = PdfReader("/home/efolatt/Projects/python/test.pdf")
delta_y=70

page = pdf.pages[0]
page.cropbox.lower_left=(200,delta_y)
page.cropbox.upper_left=(200,page.mediabox.height-delta_y)

output = page.extract_text()
output
```

Can someone show what I did wrong?